# Regular expression bracket mystery in R

Tags: regex, r, stringr

I'm trying to use `str_extract` to find dates in a text document. However, I've run into a bit of a conundrum. Generally I expect dates to come in one of two forms: 1) `June 15th, 1914` 2) `June 15, 1914`. But when I try to build a pattern to catch both of these options, I get an `NA` result.

For example, if I try to `str_extract("No. 1. June 20th, 1914.", "[:alpha:]{3,8} [0-9]{1,2}[[a-z]{2}]?, [0-9]{4}")`, I get `NA`. But if I remove the brackets around `[a-z]{2}` it works. However, if I remove the brackets, I of course get an `NA` for the string `"No. 1. June 20, 1914."`. This does, however, work if I leave the brackets.

I can of course work around this by using a simple `if/else if` statement, but I'm curious as to why this isn't working, and if there is a better way to handle these combined cases.

Comment: For another option `str_extract(x, "\\w+ \\d*\\w*, \\d*")`

Comment: @PierreLafortune, that could work but would also match strings like `June 20t, 1914`, `June , 1914.`, `June , `

Comment: @hwnd Knowing the data is the most important thing. If they are standardized to two types as the OP states, Ockham's razor prevails in supplying the best path forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not working because of the following reasons:

1. Your POSIX character class is not properly wrapped inside a bracketed expression.
2. You're trying to use a character class as an optional group construct.

Your regular expression fixed would look like:

```
x <- 'No. 1. June 20th, 1914.'
str_extract(x, '[[:alpha:]]{3,8} [0-9]{1,2}([a-z]{2})?, [0-9]{4}')
## [1] "June 20th, 1914"
```

You could modify your regular expression:

```
str_extract(x, '[a-zA-Z]+ \\d{1,2}([a-z]{2})?, \\d{4}')
```

Comment: This makes sense! Thank you! But why did it work for 2) but not for 1)?

Comment: Could be a bug or stringr wraps the POSIX class automatically, interesting.

Answer (score 4):

If you're trying to extract dates, why not use the `lubridate` package?

```
> lubridate::mdy("No. 1. June 20th, 1914.")
[1] "1914-01-20 UTC"
```

(where `mdy` is telling lubridate that the date-data appears in month-day-year order).

Comment: This is a good point - in fact, I am trying to use `lubridate`, and even used it to begin with, but for some reason if I tried to run an entire text file through `lubridate` it will always return `NA`, up until the chunk that `lubridate` is running on shrinks to around 100 characters. Since the first date in each text file doesn't occur at a regular interval (somewhere within the first 2500 characters, which is too wide a range), I use this method and then apply  `lubridate`, and save the date to a vector. Why does `lubridate` stop working for large chunks?

Comment: I dug around a little. The `ymd`-like functions all depend on `strptime` which throws an error when the input string is too long (about 1000 characters). If you are processing a textfile, why not use `readLines` to read it line-by line, and apply `mdy` to that vector? (`readLines` returns a `character` vector with an entry for each line in a file.

Comment: I only need the first date in each text file (I'm trying to automate the creation of some metadata), so I think `str_extract` makes more sense for now - unless I'm missing something? I haven't really used `readLines` before.

Comment: If you use `str_extract`, you need to be pretty confident in the way the date is represented. Writing and testing regexp can be a chore. With `readLines` you can do: `x <- readLines([your file])`. Then `y <- mdy(x)`, next `i <- which(!is.na(y))[1]` and `y[1]` is your candidate.

Answer (score 2):

```
>str_extract("No. 1. June 20, 1914.", "[[:alpha:]]{3,8} [[:digit:]]{1,2}.+?, [[:digit:]]{4}")
[1] "June 20, 1914"

> str_extract("No. 1. June 20th, 1914.", "[[:alpha:]]{3,8} [[:digit:]]{1,2}.+?, [[:digit:]]{4}")
[1] "June 20th, 1914"
```

As the . matches any character, the function returns the greatest possible sequence of any characters before ',' and then we use quantifiers + and ? for the condition

Comment: How does this answer what was wrong with his original pattern?